# Vba add hyperlink to a picture

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I have a code to add hundreds of pictures from weblinks to a sheet. It works perfectly! Now I need to modify it to add a hyperlink to each picture and I cannot get it to work. Any help is appreciated! The hyperlink is the same link that contains the picture, in this script is the variable Filename. The idea is to open the picture in a larger size if the user clicks on it.

```
Line_dest = n - 1 
Filename = Sheets("LISTOFLINKS").Cells(n, 15).Value 
Rows(Line_dest).RowHeight = 100 
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Filename).Select 
Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1) 
With shp 
     .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue 
     .Width = 180 
     If .Height > 95 Then .Height = 95 
     .Cut 
End With 
Selection.Hyperlinks.Add 
Anchor:=Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1), _
Address:=Filename
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
Anchor:=shp, _
Address:=Filename
```

and you should remove the `.Cut`. This cuts the image (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>)  and if it is removed you can not add a link to it. Alternatively you can add the hyperlink before you cut it:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Filename).Select
Set shp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=shp, Address:=Filename
With shp
     .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
     .Width = 180
     If .Height > 95 Then .Height = 95
     '.Cut 'removed that I guess you don't want the image to be cut
End With
```

Comment: Thanks! based on your help and a few changes I got it to work! The cut is because the picture is then moved to a final location.